# Angular custom Textbox with text place holder and icon

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to create a custom textbox where it requires text place holder and help icon which should popover info

[image]

on typing input, the textbox should look as below.

[image]

I check bootstrap and primeng for builtin input box. didn't find any.

Note it should be responsive. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ngx bootstrap and import only the tooltip module in your module.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip

```
import {TooltipModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

And you can add the icon using material icons. You have there the 'help' icon that looks exactly as in your example:

https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Tracking number">
    <mat-icon matSuffix tooltip="You can enter your...">help</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
```

You can have a look also in the angular documentation:

https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples